# Unwanted Icon appears on image in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image tag under li tag, i have added image using background property, there is an unexpected icon on the image comin in IE8, in FF and chrome works fine.

HTML:

```
<img class="accordionDown">
```

CSS:

```
.accordionDown {
    background: url('../images/accordian_down.png') no-repeat #E5E4E2;
    height: 35px;
    border: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Probably because you use img tag without src attribute. It's also pretty stupid, especially if you set a background image through css.

Comment: Yes, think of slash197 comment. You could have another tag, like an div just as well...

Comment: why don't u just use the src property of the image tag ? like this :<img src="../images/accordian_down.png" />

Comment: @slash197 If i use src property in the above code, accordian functionality of Jquery doesnot works, thats the reason i am here.

Answer (score 0):

please change to `<img class="accordionDown" src="Path To Image" >`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `span` in place of `image`,

And add `width` and `overflow:hidden` to you class

```
.accordionDown {
    background: url('../images/accordian_down.png') no-repeat #E5E4E2;
    height: 35px;
    width:35px;/* add width */
    overflow:hidden;/* add overflow */
    border: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: i am getting all unexpected results, it didnt solve my issue,
If i use src property in the above code, accordian functionality of Jquery doesnot works

Comment: can you make an online demo like on `fiddle`?

Comment: its bit complex, i will try all the solutions suggested and mark as answer. Thanks for the help